# How can i define an empty List for initial value of RxList of Maps

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I use Getx package in my project and i want to define a list like this in controller

```
  RxList<UserType> usersNames = [
    UserType(name: 'komail', isActive: true),
    UserType(name: 'ali', isActive: true),
  ].obs;
```

this is UserType class

```
class UserType {
  String name;
  bool isActive;

  UserType({
    required this.name,
    required this.isActive,
  });
}
```

usersNames list is empty in its initial value. but when i want to define this variable like below, i get this error.

```
  RxList<UserType> usersNames = [].obs;
```

```
A value of type 'RxList<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RxList<UserType>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'RxList<UserType>'
```

Comment: Does this work, `RxList<UserType> usersNames = <UserType>[].obs;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line, you're assigning a list of type `dynamic` to a list which has a type `UserType`.

```dart
RxList<UserType> usersNames = [].obs; // Bad
```

What you should rather do is, use:

```dart
RxList<UserType> usersNames = <UserType>[].obs; // Good
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final RxList<CustomModel> _list = new List<CustomModel>.empty().obs;
final RxList<CustomModel> _list = <CustomModel>[].obs;
```